# Upgrade Magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, magento-upgrade

I tried updating from magento **2.2.3 to 2.2.4** using the `web setup wizard`.

However the upgrade finishes with a **fatal error**. I login to my admin and it shows that it is `2.2.4` however when I go to the web setup wizard, I get the same fatal error page.

[image]

Comment: Try after deleting cache and generated folders in private browser window.

Comment: you can use command line. Its fast method

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated
chmod +x bin/magento
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: That did not work. However I changed the 'db' value to 'Files' in env.php. and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should access to the file **app/etc/env.php** then fix this command from:

```
'session' => [
'save' => 'db'
```

To :

```
'session' => [
'save' => 'files'
```